# JQuery append multiple child content to parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cordova

I have to add multiple child content to parent element dynamically using jquery , here is the example code I am referring https://github.com/linslin/pagingSlider ,
The code is so,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slidepage-container myPageContainerClass">
        <div id="badges-slidepage-1" page="1" class="psPage center current">
            <div class="content">
               <h2>Page 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="badges-slidepage-2" page="2" class="psPage right">
            <div class="content">
               <h2>Page 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="badges-slidepage-3" page="3" class="psPage right">
            <div class="content">
               <h2>Page 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="badges-slidepage-4" page="4" class="psPage right">
            <div class="content">
               <h2>Page 4</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am able to add child elements to parent

```
 var parentwrapper= $("<div/>").attr('id', 'wrapper');
    var firstDiv= $("<div/>").addClass("slidepage-container myPageContainerClass");
    var firstPage= $("<div/>").attr("id", "badges-slidepage-1").attr("page", "1").addClass("psPage center current");
    var contentDiv= $("<div/>").addClass("content");
    var firstcontent= $("<div/>").addClass("dealerNextTo dealerRectangleBox rectangleTopLeft").text("promptText");
      
    var secondPage = $("<div/>").attr("id", "badges-slidepage-2").attr("page", "2").addClass("psPage right");
    var secondContent= $("<div/>").addClass("dealerNextTo dealerRectangleBox rectangleTopLeft").text("promptText");
    
    var myFinalVar =  $(parentwrapper).append(firstDiv).append(firstPage).append(contentDiv).append(firstcontent).append(secondPage).append(secondContent);
    
    $(myFinalVar).appendTo('body');
```

but it is adding to firstpage ContentDiv only,

*How to achieve it. Any ideas? (I'm new to Jquery)*

Comment: You are appending everything into $(parentwrapper)

Comment: yes misunderstood append concept..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are chaining `append`s to add the elements you created like this:

```
var myFinalVar = $(parentwrapper).append(firstDiv).append(firstPage).append(contentDiv)
                                 .append(firstcontent).append(secondPage).append(secondContent);
```

When you chain appends, elements do not get added to the *previous* element in the chain, they are all added directly to the *first* element. In your code, you are adding all elements as direct children of `parentwrapper`.

You need to add each child (or set of siblingss) to their parent separately, e.g. you need to add only `firstDiv` to `parentwrapper`:

```
var myFinalVar = $(parentwrapper).append(firstDiv);
```

`firstPage` and `secondPage` are being appended to the same parent, so you *can* chain those like this:

```
$(firstDiv).append(firstPage).append(secondPage);  // appending to the SAME parent
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var parentwrapper = $("<div/>").attr('id', 'wrapper');
var firstDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("slidepage-container myPageContainerClass");
var firstPage = $("<div/>").attr("id", "badges-slidepage-1").attr("page", "1").addClass("psPage center current");
var contentDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("content");
var firstcontent = $("<div/>").addClass("dealerNextTo dealerRectangleBox rectangleTopLeft").text("Page 1 content div");
var secondPage = $("<div/>").attr("id", "badges-slidepage-2").attr("page", "2").addClass("psPage right");
var secondContent = $("<div/>").addClass("dealerNextTo dealerRectangleBox rectangleTopLeft").text("Page 2 content div");

var myFinalVar = $(parentwrapper).append(firstDiv);
// chain appends to add to the SAME div
$(firstDiv).append(firstPage).append(secondPage);
$(firstPage).append(contentDiv);
$(contentDiv).append(firstcontent);
$(secondPage).append(secondContent);

$(myFinalVar).appendTo('body');
```

```css
#wrapper { padding: 10px; background: #eee; }

.slidepage-container.myPageContainerClass,
.content, 
.psPage,
.dealerNextTo{ border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px;}

.psPage { margin-bottom:20px; }

.rectangleTopLeft { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

FYI you also seem to be missing an element on the secondPage elements - it doesn't have a `.content` div.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped :) and also now i am able to understand the "append" concept clearly..nice explanation with example...grateful

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you may want to try:

```
// append first content to contentDiv
contentDiv.append(firstcontent);
// append contentDiv to firstPage
firstPage.append(contentDiv);
// append firstPage to firstDiv
firstDiv.append(firstPage);

// again append secondContent to secondPage
secondPage.append(secondContent);
firstDiv.append(secondPage);

var myFinalVar = $(parentwrapper).append(firstDiv);

$(myFinalVar).appendTo('body');
```